# Restore Missing "Settings" (gnome-control-center) Icon in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, icons, settings

I have been running Ubuntu 18.04 for a couple of weeks. I upgraded from 16.04 and all went smoothly.

I am not sure what I changed, but this morning I noticed that the "Settings" Icon that launches gnome-control-center is missing from "Show Applications" and the applications menu as well. When I searched from "Show Applications" for gnome-control-center or just settings, nothing showed up.

So, I figured I must have accidentally removed it and figured a reinstall of the package would resolve the issue. I have searched and found several postings where this worked. I tried:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

And then rebooted - which reinstalled the gnome-control-center and I could then launch it from the command line. However, there was still no Settings Icon in any of the menus.

I also tried many other suggestions including:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

However, none of these has been successful in restoring the icon into "Show Applications" or any applications menu.

Anyone have any suggestions on something I haven't tried? Would be much appreciated.  Or, is there a way to just manually recreate the icon?

Output of `locate gnome-control-center.desktop`:

```
/usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop 
/home/dccrens/.local/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop
/home/dccrens/.gnome/apps/gnome-control-center.desktop
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 desktop on kernel 4.15.0-45-generic.

Comment: @Klufy  Thanks.  Locate shows  /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop  /home/dccrens/.local/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop  and /home/dccrens/.gnome/apps/gnome-control-center.desktop

Comment: @Klufy

cat shows: $ cat /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop [Desktop Entry] Name=Settings

Comment: cat /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Settings
# Translators: Do NOT translate or transliterate this text (this is an icon file name)!
Icon=gnome-control-center
Exec=gnome-control-center
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-control-center
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=shell
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.28.2

Comment: # Translators: Search terms to find this application. Do NOT translate or localize the semicolons! The list MUST also end with a semicolon!
Keywords=Preferences;Settings;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-control-center-2.0

Comment: @Klufy - Your question put me on the answer! Copying the /usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop to the two other locations in my home directory fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcuts in "Show Application" menu is shown by the Desktop Entry of the corresponding app. According to output of `locate gnome-control-center.desktop`, there are two extra *gnome-control-center.desktop* located in */home/dccrens/.gnome/apps/* and */home/dccrens/.local/share/applications/*  which are creating the issue. Delete that files using Nautilus or `rm /home/dccrens/.gnome/apps/gnome-control-center.desktop /home/dccrens/.local/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop`.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I just ran

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

rebooted the system, and it was restored. It is now working fine again.

Answer (score 2):

Call me dumb, but I was "missing" settings in `gnome-control-center` because it opened in a submenu (Devices). Reinstalling didn't work. Googling didn't work.

All I had to do was click [image: the back button] in the top left...

Comment: Same here, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was suddenly missing Settings in my Ubuntu18.04.3LTS; not in the Launcher nor in the Applications anymore. 
did re-install "gnome control center" from the Ubuntu software center and now Settings is working fine again, and the icon is back in Launcher and Applications.