# Ubuntu Control Center icon is gone

Tags: settings

Ubuntu Control Center is gone from Application menu & Desktop.
I have Ubuntu 18.04.
Please help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117175/restore-missing-settings-gnome-control-center-icon-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

The suggested links didn't help.
I tried to reinstall gnome-control-centre, and make it come up via Terminal, but it appeared empty page.
So, once the solution can't be found on the Internet, I have to reinstall Ubuntu. That's proved working.

Answer (score 0):

Run it using terminal first and look at logs in terminal if nothing wrong happens:

```
gnome-control-center
```

Run the next commands to make sure you have only one *Gnome control center*:

```
find /usr/share/applications/* -iname *control* | grep center
```

Output: `/usr/share/applications/gnome-control-center.desktop`

```
find /home/$USER/* -iname *control* | grep center
```

Here's nothing should be displayed

Open other terminal window and run `journalctl -f` to watch what will happen during `.desktop` file opening, editing, saving and closing.

Open your `gnome-control-center.desktop` file and make sure it looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Settings
# Translators: Do NOT translate or transliterate this text (this is an icon file name)!
Icon=org.gnome.Settings
Exec=gnome-control-center
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-control-center
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=shell
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.34.1
# Translators: Search terms to find this application. Do NOT translate or localize the semicolons! The list MUST also end with a semicolon!
Keywords=Preferences;Settings;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-control-center-2.0
```

It could disappear if binary in `Exec` could not be found. So try to modify it as follows:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-control-center
```

or

```
Exec=/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/gnome-control-center'
```

Also, `whereis gnome-control-center` could help in binary path identifying. Check also that binary owner and rights by:

```
ls -ailh /usr/bin/ | grep control
```

Save and close editor's window.

And to reinstall it yo could better use:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-control-center && sudo apt clean && sido apt update && sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

And you could also create new user, login with it and check if for the new user the issue occurs or not.

If your apt system could not locate `gnome-control-center` package, make sure your [repositories list](https://gist.github.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1) configured correctly.

Comment: Gryu, thanks for your answer. I tried to follow the instruction, and got only long Terminal writings, not Command Center.

Comment: Try to reinstall it with purge

Comment: Thank you. (To begin with, all that bull happened after one of daily updates.) Now, I tried to apt-get purge. Terminal answered that the stuff didn't exist. I tried to install && reinstall. Terminal answered, "unable to locate package center." So, how do you think I can reinstall the center?